# Eviction maxEntries value cannot be less than or equal to zero if eviction is enabled

Tags: java, spring, maven, jboss

I have this standalone.xml in my jboss:

```
<cache-container name="hibernate" default-cache="local-query" module="org.jboss.as.jpa.hibernate:4" statistics-enabled="true">
                <transport lock-timeout="60000"/>
                <local-cache name="local-query" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </local-cache>
                <invalidation-cache name="entity" mode="SYNC" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <transaction mode="NON_XA"/>
                    <eviction strategy="LRU" max-entries="10000"/>
                    <expiration max-idle="100000"/>
                </invalidation-cache>
                <replicated-cache name="timestamps" mode="ASYNC" statistics-enabled="true">
                    <transaction mode="NONE"/>
                    <eviction strategy="NONE"/>
                </replicated-cache>
            </cache-container>
```

When I start my jboss I obtain this error in my console:

> JBAS014612: Operation ("add") failed - address: ([
> ("subsystem" => "infinispan"),
> ("cache-container" => "ejb"),
> ("replicated-cache" => "repl") ]): org.infinispan.config.ConfigurationException: Eviction maxEntries
> value cannot be less than or equal to zero if eviction is enabled     at
> org.infinispan.configuration.cache.EvictionConfigurationBuilder.validate(EvictionConfigurationBuilder.java:84)
> at
> org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.validate(ConfigurationBuilder.java:187)
> at
> org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:203)
> at
> org.infinispan.configuration.cache.ConfigurationBuilder.build(ConfigurationBuilder.java:198)
> at
> org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheAdd.installRuntimeServices(CacheAdd.java:217)
> at
> org.jboss.as.clustering.infinispan.subsystem.CacheAdd.performRuntime(CacheAdd.java:186)
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractAddStepHandler$1.execute(AbstractAddStepHandler.java:75)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:702)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.doCompleteStep(AbstractOperationContext.java:537)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.completeStepInternal(AbstractOperationContext.java:338)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:314)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at
> org.jboss.as.controller.ParallelBootOperationStepHandler$ParallelBootTask.run(ParallelBootOperationStepHandler.java:355)
> [jboss-as-controller-7.5.0.Final-redhat-21.jar:7.5.0.Final-redhat-21]
> at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]    at
> java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
> [rt.jar:1.8.0_181]    at
> org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:122)
> [jboss-threads-2.1.2.Final-redhat-1.jar:2.1.2.Final-redhat-1]

Anyone can help me?